# Error "Task attempt 0 is already registered" with RDD from Kafka Consumer in Spark-Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

App running on IntelliJ with Spark local mode.

In the loop when Consumer from Kafka topic by Spark-Streaming:

```
if ((_rdd != null) && (_rdd.count() > 0) && (!_rdd.isEmpty())) {
    val input = _rdd.map(x => getData(x)).map(x => x.Content.toString)
    input.foreach(println)
    val ins = input.map(x => x.split(",")).map{f: Array[String] => Tuple2(f(0), f(1))}.reduceByKey(_+_).map(l => (l
      ._1, l._2.split(" ").map(i => i.trim.toLowerCase))).map{case (key, values) => (key, values.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_
      .size)
      .toArray)}
    ins.foreach(_._2.foreach(print(_) + " "))
    //.........MORE CODE HERE............
}
//Start the stream
streamCtx.start()
streamCtx.awaitTermination()
```

The error is kind of:

> 19/05/08 15:55:05 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Task attempt 0 is already registered
>   at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
>   at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.registerTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:156)

But, if i use input (RDD) by parallelize an array of string, everything is ok.

Please help me figure out the error!